# Is jQuery animation CPU intensive?

Tags: jquery

I have a page that uses the Slider Revolution jQuery plugin by ThemePunch to implement Ken Burns zooms and pans (www.zoespicks.com). These work fine on  desktops and on smart phones but some tablets have trouble. Samsung's Tab Pro 12.2, for example, can't do them.  Instead of a smooth animation you see a "jerk" about every 3/4 of a second. An iPad Air 2, on the other hand, plays them as smooth as silk. I'm guessing that these jQuery animations are extremely CPU intensive, with jQuery basically calculating new values and outputting them as fast as it can to create the animation. Smart phones work because there aren't that many pixels to move around, but tablets have four times as many pixels and unless they've beefed up the CPU & graphics processor from the smartphone, they can't handle it.  It appears that Samsung didn't and Apple did.  Just going from the iPad Air to the iPad Air2, e.g., Apple increased the processor performance by 40% and the graphics performance by 2.5X.

Am I thinking straight here?  Is jQuery animation highly CPU intensive and likely the cause of what I'm seeing?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's also depending on the browser you'll use since it's not "just" the jQuery it's also the interpreter of that code which comes into action.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. After some more thought I have to think that it's not a CPU problem but a GPU problem  It shouldn't be any harder for jQuery to crank out the CSS values in a smart phone (where the animation works) than in a tablet, but the tablet has 4X as many pixels to relocate. I think that Samsung probably didn't upgrade the GPU much going from a phone to tablet, while pixels went up 4x.  Apple, on  the other hand made a big improvement going from the phone to the tablet and then another big improvement going from the Air tablet to the Air 2 tablet.